# Check if Powershell Module is installed in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

Is it possible to check if a powershell module ist installed in C#?

I need a C# condition if a module is / or is not installed.

I know how to use powershell in C#, but how become a response from Powershell?

Thanks for reading my question and i hope anyone can give me some hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a reference to `System.Management.Automation` and use the [`PowerShell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to invoke `Get-Module` cmdlet to check if a specific module has been installed:

```
var exists = false;
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    string moduleName = "something";
    ps.AddScript($"Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name {moduleName}");
    var result = ps.Invoke();
    exists = result.Count > 0;
}
```

**Note:** To add a reference to `System.Management.Automation`, you can install the NuGet package using `Install-Package System.Management.Automation.dll` Or if you want to see where the dll is located on your system, using powershell console, you can see `[PSObject].Assembly.Location` and pick it.

Comment: In your answer is an issue. result.Count is an Property not a method ;-)

Comment: In fact I used the linq `Count()` extension method which is usable when you have `using System.Linq;`

Comment: `result.Count` is a Property not a method

Comment: Oh ha. Thanks! My misstake.

Comment: No worries, I'll change the code to use property to make it less confusing :)

Comment: @Marcus you might want to accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: The way you use `AddScript` is susceptible to injections. You should really use something like this instead: `ps.AddCommand("Get-Module").AddParameter("ListAvailable").AddParameter("Name", moduleName)`

Comment: Marcus, if you get the input from user, be careful about the risk which is mentioned by @PetSerAl